# Grails Spring Security plugin - requestmap for action

Tags: grails, spring-security

Is it possible to secure an action by its name in Spring Security using Requestmap? e.g. I need users to authenticate to be able to create and update, but for anonymous users to view.

Basically I want to achieve something like

```
new Requestmap(url: '/*/create', configAttribute: 'IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED').save()
```

for all actions named 'create' regardless of controllers.

Where might I begin to look to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

This blog shows how you would do that:

http://blog.springsource.com/2010/08/11/simplified-spring-security-with-grails/

It seems like you want to look under "Dynamic request maps" in the blog. You will need to add a couple lines to Config.groovy, and then you can start creating `Requestmap`s just like you have there:

```
import grails.plugins.springsecurity.SecurityConfigType
...
grails.plugins.springsecurity.securityConfigType = SecurityConfigType.Requestmap
```

The blog doesn't show an example of the wildcard in the middle, but from my experience I'm pretty sure that will work.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately I also thought that the wildcard in the middle could work for the requestmap. But actually it doesn't work and that's why I'm asking...

Comment: I'm using wildcards in the middle doing it the static way, so maybe the `*` just needs to be escaped or unescaped or something since now persistence backend is involved...

Comment: Still not working, what do you mean by escaping the '*'? I tried sth like this
`new Requestmap(url: '/\\*/edit', configAttribute: 'ROLE_ADMIN')`...